# Why won't my page go to another page even though I'm using the same method as before?

Tags: javascript, html

So in an attempt to learn some web design and a little bit of game/puzzle design, I decided to dip my toes into making an ARG (Alternate Reality Game if you didn't know) and all of the normal pages work fine. However, when I started making a login page where some of the secrets are going to be hidden, it won't move to the next page.

The method I've been using to move around pages is the standard `window.location.href = '/pages/*INSERT FILENAME*.html'`, and for the entire rest of the site it works as expected. But for the login page, I've been trying to implement a very basic conditional that checks for a matching username and password, of which I had set up a test user that would move the page to a over-glorified 'Hello World' page. But for whatever reason, it won't move. I had even set it up to where just pressing the button, regardless of input, would send you to the hello world page and it still didn't work. The page in question is the /pages/login.html, and it's trying to go to /pages/helloTest.html, login.html is as follows;

```
<!-- src = /pages/login.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Authentication</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body class="login">
    <center>
      <form action="">
        <label for="user">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user"> <br>
        <label for="passwrd">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" /> <br /><br />
        <button id="login">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </center>
    <script>
      var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
      var passwrd = document.getElementById("passwrd").value;
      /* This was supposed to be a function to check the credentials and send the player to the respective page.
       function checkCredential() {
        if ((user == "TWPD-TEST") & (passwrd == "TEST")) {
          window.location.href = "/pages/helloTest.html";
        }
      }*/
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if ((user == "TWPD-TEST") & (passwrd == "TEST")) {
          window.location.href = "/pages/helloTest.html";
        }
      });
      passwrd.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          button.click;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I have tried making to where the conditional was just inside of an `onclick` event in the button and scrap the entire script, but still nothing. The page will just reload and move nowhere. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

For additional context, I'm deploying the site locally using the Live Server extension for VSCode on a Windows 10 machine (since my machine apparently doesn't meet the spec requirements for Win11).

Comment: can you comment out all your js code and put this and see if it redirects: ```setInterval(() => { location.href = "/pages/home.html" }, 1000)```

Comment: It does redirect, now I just need it to do that when it passes the conditional, I'll test that now. @seriously

Comment: You're setting `user` and `passwrd` when the page first loads, not when the user clicks on the button. So they don't contain what the user entered.

Comment: `button.click` is missing parentheses: `button.click()`.

Comment: Move the variable assignments inside the click event listener.

Comment: Basic debugging would have revealed this. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Barmar I don't even understand why most beginners guide teach by using forms why not just plane input tags?

Comment: @seriously I think forms are useful for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an event listener to `button` because that isn't the ID of any element. Button is the type, not the ID.

You need to get a reference to the specific button and then add the listener to that. Example:

```
var loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if ((user == "TWPD-TEST") & (passwrd == "TEST")) {
      window.location.href = "/pages/helloTest.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: why use bitwise AND operator?

Comment: It's not working, it's still just reloading the page and staying there instead of actually redirecting like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("login");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
  var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var passwrd = document.getElementById("passwrd").value;
  if (user === "TWPD-TEST" && passwrd === "TEST") {
    window.location.href = "/pages/home.html";
  }
});

var passwrdInput = document.getElementById("passwrd");
passwrdInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    button.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Authentication</title>
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body class="login">
  <center>
    <form id="loginForm">
      <label for="user">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user" name="user"> <br>
      <label for="passwrd">Password: </label>
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" /> <br /><br />
      <button id="login">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, and learned to never use `<form>` again.

The issue completely went away when I removed the `<form>` tags, so I'm thinking that maybe the form was trying to do something that contradicted other actions in the script. I'm pretty sure the site was still getting input, but it wouldn't redirect for some reason. So, what all happened was;

1. I removed the `<form>` tags
2. gave the button an `onclick` event that calls a function to collect and check the information from the textboxes

The only issue I'm having now is that it's not responding to the listeners and I have to have it basically call a function to work, so I'll have to keep investigating that, but other than that it works!

In the end, this is what the page code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Authentication</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body class="login">
    <center>
      <label for="user">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user" name="user" /> <br />
      <label for="passwrd">Password: </label>
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" /> <br /><br />
      <button id="login" onclick="checkCredential()">Submit</button>
    </center>
    <script>
      var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
      var passwrd = document.getElementById("passwrd").value;
      var loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
      loginButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if ((user == "TWPD-TEST") & (passwrd == "TEST")) {
          window.location.href = "/pages/helloTest.html";
        }
      });
      function checkCredential() {
        user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        passwrd = document.getElementById("passwrd").value;
        checkAccess();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the form has default behaviour in the browser. You should add a `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the event.